# Detect if audio will play on desktop browser

Tags: javascript, audio, browser

**Problem:** The audio on https://namedrop.io/keshavmalani won't play on a browser. Specifically this happens on Internet Explorer on computers within a corporate infrastructure and they have a setup that blocks javascript for audio at least (not sure what else they block that his may be happening)

**Desired Solution:** I want to be able to display a message on the page saying something like, "The name recording won't play due to your browser settings"

Is there a way I can do this? The noscript tag doesn't fire on their browser either

I'm using jplayer to play the name recordings

Comment: Have you tried using `<audio>` without javascript?

Comment: So I tried with this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all And it did play - so is Javascript the only problem? How can I make it failover to the <audio> method. 

My reason for using jPlayer is to have cross platform/browser compatibility. But that doesn't seem to be true. Can I change the GUI of the play button on audio tag to play on mine?

Comment: Not entirely certain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: **Goal**: Be able to play the name recordings (when user clicks the play button) on NameDrop pages, on all platforms and devices, as simply as possible. I have .wav and .mp3 files available for each recording

**Current Approach**: Use jPlayer as it claims to be light weight and cross platform

**Problem I run into**: I believe because jPlayer is javascript based, it is getting blocked sometimes (on Internet Explorer...the problem I mentioned in my question)

Comment: Try https://jsfiddle.net/m6mpfmaf/

Comment: So I need to format the player and this one is simple and worked: http://codepen.io/katzkode/pen/Kfgix#anon-login

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution by @guest271314 was to use the  tags instead of a javascript based player, which worked but since I needed to change the player (css etc.), I had to do something more. Did some more digging and found this: http://codepen.io/katzkode/pen/Kfgix#anon-login and that worked too

```
<audio id="music" preload="true">
  <source src="http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/interlude.mp3">
            <source src="http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/interlude.ogg">
    </audio>
<div id="audioplayer">
    <button id="pButton" class="play" onclick="play()"></button>
  <div id="timeline">    
          <div id="playhead"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems the problem could have been that jPlayer is introducing something into their player that is not working on IE. Thanks @guest271314